# Complex Filtering Operations in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, filtering

Currently I'm performing calculations on a database that contains information on how loans are paid by borrowers. It is a huge dataset so I'm using PySpark and have just faced with an issue of how to use advanced filtering operations.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Name    ID     ContractDate LoanSum ClosingDate
A       ID1    2022-10-10   10      2022-10-15 
A       ID1    2022-10-15   15      null
A       ID1    2022-10-30   20      2022-11-10
B       ID2    2022-11-11   15      2022-10-14
B       ID2    2022-12-10   30      null
B       ID2    2022-12-12   35      2022-12-14
C       ID3    2022-12-19   19      2022-11-10
D       ID4    2022-12-10   10      null
D       ID4    2022-12-12   40      2022-11-29
```

My goal is to create a dataframe that contains all loans issued to specific borrowers (group by unique ID) where the the first loan is not yet closed, but the second is already given to a borrower and the difference between loansums is less or equal then 5.

In other words, I have to obtain the following table (expected result):

```
Name    ID     ContractDate LoanSum Status
A       ID1    2022-10-15   15      null 
A       ID1    2022-10-30   20      2022-11-10
B       ID3    2022-12-10   30      null
B       ID3    2022-12-12   35      2022-12-14
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please re-check that your input `ID3` has only one record in your input data 
and in the output desired output `ID3` should be `ID2`. Please check my answer also below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PySpark [Window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html) PartitionBy Unique ID. To check if next loan is already closed you can use [Lead](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lead.html) Function. Similarly Lag get the previous record value based on partition.

Here in this example, I used Lead and Lag together to make sure that both criteria meet on both rows. This is useful to create a check column and output these rows based on the check.

Check this solution.

```
from datetime import date
from decimal import Decimal
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


data = [
('A','ID1','2022-10-10',10,'2022-10-150'),
('A','ID1','2022-10-15',15,'null'),
('A','ID1','2022-10-30',20,'2022-11-10'),
('B','ID2','2022-11-11',15,'2022-10-14'),
('B','ID2','2022-12-10',30,'null'),
('B','ID2','2022-12-12',35,'2022-12-14'),
('C','ID3','2022-12-19',19,'2022-11-10'),
('D','ID4','2022-12-10',10,'null'),
('D','ID4','2022-12-12',40,'2022-11-29')]

cols = ['Name','ID','ContractDate','LoanSum','ClosingDate'] 
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

print('Input---->')
df.show()

next_record = f.lead(f.col('ClosingDate')).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy("ContractDate")).alias("next_ClosingDate")
prev_record = f.lag(f.col('ClosingDate')).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy("ContractDate")).alias("prev_ClosingDate")

next_loan_sum = f.lead(f.col('LoanSum')).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy("ContractDate")).alias("next_LoanSum")
prev_loan_sum = f.lag(f.col('LoanSum')).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy("ContractDate")).alias("prev_LoanSum")


print('Output---->')
df.withColumn(
    'check',
    f.when(
        ( (f.col('ClosingDate')=='null') & (next_record !='null')  ) |
        ( (f.col('ClosingDate')!='null') & (prev_record =='null')  ) , 1).otherwise(0)
).withColumn('looan_sum_check',  
             f.when(  ((next_loan_sum - f.col('LoanSum') ) <=5) | ((f.col('LoanSum') - prev_loan_sum ) <=5) , 1).otherwise(0)     
).filter('check=1 and looan_sum_check=1').drop('check','looan_sum_check').show()
```

Results Output

```
Input---->
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
|Name| ID|ContractDate|LoanSum|ClosingDate|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-10|     10|2022-10-150|
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-15|     15|       null|
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-30|     20| 2022-11-10|
|   B|ID2|  2022-11-11|     15| 2022-10-14|
|   B|ID2|  2022-12-10|     30|       null|
|   B|ID2|  2022-12-12|     35| 2022-12-14|
|   C|ID3|  2022-12-19|     19| 2022-11-10|
|   D|ID4|  2022-12-10|     10|       null|
|   D|ID4|  2022-12-12|     40| 2022-11-29|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+

Output---->
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
|Name| ID|ContractDate|LoanSum|ClosingDate|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-15|     15|       null|
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-30|     20| 2022-11-10|
|   B|ID2|  2022-12-10|     30|       null|
|   B|ID2|  2022-12-12|     35| 2022-12-14|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
```